# Errors After Upgrading from EXTJS 4.2 to EXTJS 6.x

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd, extjs6

So far, I've done the upgrade in two ways:

**1)** I set up a fresh `sencha app generate [appName]` and transferred the **4.2** files and directories to **6.x**. After setting them up, an error occurs when doing a `sencha app build`:

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/backoffice-test/EcommBackoffice/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:381: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/backoffice-test/EcommBackoffice/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:382: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.ux.grid.filters.Filters
rareyes@MAKDL-RAREYES:/var/www/html/backoffice-test/EcommBackoffice$
```

Along with this, upon loading the app, the console error is giving out these lines:

```
http://localhost:1841/EcommBackoffice/Overrides/view/Table.js?_dc=1452581765612`
http://localhost:1841/EcommBackoffice/Overrides/selection/Model.js?_dc=1452581765612`
[E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.
[E] [Loader] The following classes failed to load:
[E] [Loader] Overrides.view.Table from Overrides/view/Table.js
[E] [Loader] Overrides.selection.Model from Overrides/selection/Model.js
[E] [Loader] EcommBackoffice.Application from app/Application.js
```

**2)** Being stucked on the first one, my second approach was to simply do a `sencha app upgrade -ext` on the existing application. It successfully updated except when doing a `sencha app build` it gives out a similar error such as:

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/backoffice-2.0/src/main/webapp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:381: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/html/backoffice-2.0/src/main/webapp/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:382: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature
```

and a short console error of: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined`

This occurs when I edit `index.html` and replace `x-compile` snippet:

```
<!-- <x-compile> -->

<!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<script src="ext/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

<!-- </x-compile> -->
```

to this:

```
<script id="microloader" data-app="a32fd6d2-db0c-4c4b-a6a2-4185b3ee3fd4" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Prior to editing `index.html`, a different error is being thrown with `x-compile`:

```
/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:382: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Mixed-Mode x-compile and microload markup is currently unsupported
```

This is the reason why I opted for the supported Microloader provided by 6.x

I am quite on a lost here. ExtJS apparently has no proper Sencha guide to upgrade directly from **4.x to 6.x**. It only does a one step higher upgrade such as **4.x to 5.x**, and **5.x to 6.x**. Even then, the guide for these are not very clear and IMHO, lacks documentation.

Anyone who can point where the problem is with the errors I provided?

Comment: For Some requested files failed to load issue go to console and execute this line --> Ext.Loader.missingQueue and try to find why renaming file are not loading..

`Ext.Loader.missingQueue` will give you a exact queue of remaining files

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Cmd error message says it loud and clear:

```
Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.ux.grid.filters.Filters
```

This means that ExtJS6 does not provide `Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filters`, which is required somewhere in your application.

As the Ext documentation states, everything from `Ext.ux` namespace is not upgrade-safe, because it is user-provided content that Sencha has found useful and added to the Ext zip file. Normally, you would just search the internet for available ExtJS 6.0.x implementations of the ux features that are missing from the official zip file; or write them yourself.

But for your special case, I believe that they moved gridfilters from ux into the official branch in ExtJS 4.2.x, then removed the alias in ExtJS 5, and finally, in ExtJS 6, they replaced the feature with a plugin.

So please have a look at [`Ext.grid.filters.Filters`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.filters.Filters), I believe it does what you need, but you would have to rewrite parts of your code to make use of it. (change the require, move the reference from features to plugins, possibly account for other changes.)

I think that the second error message ("[E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.") means the same as the first one, and I would expect something like `requires:['Ext.ux.grid.filters.Filters']` in `Overrides/view/Table.js`. (`Overrides.selection.Model` isn't loaded because it requires `Overrides.view.Table`, and `EcommBackoffice.Application` isn't loaded because it references `Overrides.selection.Model`)